# What language does this look like?

Tags: language, scotland

I was hoping someone here could help tell me what language this is?
The hint for this is Mary Queen of Scots, but I have no background in historical languages, and was hoping maybe someone here does.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this from?

Comment: Part of a riddle, and I notice some of the characters from greek. As it turns out though some of the symbols are purely mathematical.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am fairly sure this is [Mary's cipher](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/spies/ciphers/mary/ma1.htm) (here are similar [specimen](https://www.google.com/search?q=mary%20queen%20of%20scots%20cipher&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X)). It's a fairly simple encryption scheme and was indeed broken by her contemporary enemies in the 16th century.

Comment: Better image source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Mary-cipher-code.jpg